# MySQL tinyint to boolean

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, sqldatatypes, tinyint

So I have a `tinyint` datatype column in my database where I store values from `0` to `2`.

It is my understanding that MySQL treats any non-zero number in a `tinyint` column as true (in this case `1` and `2`) and the `0` as false. However, when I perform a query that retrieves certain information from the table where the `tinyint` row is `true`, it only works for the rows that have `1` as the value. In other words, the rows that have `2` as a value are not seen as `true` by the query (and the `0` is seen as `false`). The query would go something like:

```
SELECT data FROM table WHERE active=true
```

Where `active` is of datatype `tinyint` and it has been previously assigned values of `0`, `1` or `2` depending on the case.

I'm fairly new to MySQL, so I don't know if there's some detail that I could be missing here, but I can't figure out why it's not returning the requested data on the rows with 2 as the value. Any thoughts could help here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To MySQL, because `2` is neither `1` nor `0`, then `2` is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`. Consider:

```
SELECT 2 = TRUE, 2 = FALSE;
```

This returns:

```
| 2 = TRUE | 2 = FALSE |
| -------- | --------- |
| 0        | 0         |
```

You would need to express the condition differently, like:

```
SELECT data FROM table WHERE active > 0
```

This will also work (any non-zero value is considered true, see further):

```
SELECT data FROM table WHERE active;
```

---

This behavior is [documented in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html), which states:

> `BOOL, BOOLEAN`
>
> These types are synonyms for `TINYINT(1)`. A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true.

```
mysql> SELECT IF(0, 'true', 'false');
+------------------------+
| IF(0, 'true', 'false') |
+------------------------+
| false                  |
+------------------------+

mysql> SELECT IF(1, 'true', 'false');
+------------------------+
| IF(1, 'true', 'false') |
+------------------------+
| true                   |
+------------------------+

mysql> SELECT IF(2, 'true', 'false');
+------------------------+
| IF(2, 'true', 'false') |
+------------------------+
| true                   |
+------------------------+
```

> However, the values `TRUE` and `FALSE` are merely aliases for 1 and 0, respectively, as shown here:

```
mysql> SELECT IF(0 = FALSE, 'true', 'false');
+--------------------------------+
| IF(0 = FALSE, 'true', 'false') |
+--------------------------------+
| true                           |
+--------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT IF(1 = TRUE, 'true', 'false');
+-------------------------------+
| IF(1 = TRUE, 'true', 'false') |
+-------------------------------+
| true                          |
+-------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT IF(2 = TRUE, 'true', 'false');
+-------------------------------+
| IF(2 = TRUE, 'true', 'false') |
+-------------------------------+
| false                         |
+-------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT IF(2 = FALSE, 'true', 'false');
+--------------------------------+
| IF(2 = FALSE, 'true', 'false') |
+--------------------------------+
| false                          |
+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: `SELECT data FROM table WHERE active` *will* (not should) work as (as the manual says) any non-zero value is considered true. You might also want to consider adding `SELECT IF(2, 'true', 'false');` and `SELECT IF(0, 'true', 'false');` to your examples. Otherwise a really comprehensive answer which SO could use more of...

Comment: @Nick: thanks for your positive feedback and suggestions! I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much! Using "WHERE active" instead of "WHERE active=true" worked perfectly.